# How to format an array in PHP according to my needs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple destination database,

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users,rating WHERE users.user_id=rating.user_id GROUP BY rating.user_id");

$output=array();
while($hsl=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

$str=$hsl['username'];

$sql1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM destination,rating WHERE rating.dest_id=destination.dest_id AND rating.user_id='$hsl[user_id]'");

while($hsl1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
$user_id=$hsl1['user_id'];
$title=$hsl1['title'];
$rating1=$hsl1['1_rating'];
$rating2=$hsl1['2_rating'];
$rating3=$hsl1['3_rating'];
$rating4=$hsl1['4_rating'];
$avg=($rating1+$rating2+$rating3+$rating4) / 4;
$str1=$title;
$str2=$avg;
```

How to format the array to get the result of each user as below?

```
$rekom =  array(
"user1" => array("Monumen Nasional" => 3.25, 
              "Kota Tua" => 3,
                "Tidung Island" => 2),

"user2" => array("Monumen Nasional" => 3.5, "Kota Tua" => 4.25,
                  "Tidung Island" => 2),

"user3" => array("Monumen Nasional" => 2.25, "Kota Tua" => 4.5,
                "Tidung Island" => 3.75),

"user4" => array("Monumen Nasional" => 2, "Kota Tua" => 4, "Tidung Island" => 4),

"user5" => array("Monumen Nasional" => 4.25, "Tidung Island" => 4)
```

);

I have tried this code but cannot parse all of users :

```
$rekom = array($str => array($title => $str2));
```

Comment: Please read about [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: Your title seems completely different to your actual question, can you please reword your title?

Comment: @AlexHowansky thank you for the references. 

Script47 Thanks for the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `joins` to get all information that you need so you can have one query instead of 1 + number of users in database. That can have a huge performance benefit if you have a lot of users.

Below I have assumed that you save destination name in a column `title` and these values 'user1', 'user2' ... are stored in `user_id` column. If column names are different feel free to make changes to my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
        INNER JOIN rating ON users.user_id=rating.user_id
        INNER JOIN destination ON rating.dest_id = destination.dest_id";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$reviews = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $rating = ($row['1_rating'] + $row['2_rating'] + $row['3_rating'] + $row['4_rating']) / 4;
    $reviews[$row['user_id']][$row['title']] = $rating;
}

print_r($reviews);
```

This will get you all destination that have reviews from users.

**Edit**
You can calculate average by adding `AVG(1_rating + 2_rating + 3_rating + 4_rating)` in your `SELECT`. Also you should add `group by dest_id, user_id`

Comment: Hello Mr. Edison, your code running well and generate all the user reviews. Thank you so much... :)